# Changing a user status flag, with validation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, validation, active-record

I am writing a function which on update of any attribute of model sets the status of variable `is_kyc_verified` to false.

Here is the code of the User model and the method which changes the status:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  before_update :change_kyc_status, unless: :is_kyc_verified_changed?

  #Associations
  has_one  :address, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :kyc, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :pan_detail, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :document, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :nominee_details, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bank_details, dependent: :destroy

  #Accept Attributes for associated model

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :kyc, :pan_detail,
                                :document, :nominee_details, :bank_details,
                                allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank


  #validates
  validates :name, :mobile_no, :gender, :dob,  presence: true
  validates :mobile_no, numericality: true, length: { is: 10 }

  private
  ##
  # Check if is_kyc_verified is set to true
  # if 'yes' then alert user and set is_kyc_verified to false
  def change_kyc_status
    self.is_kyc_verified = false if self.valid? and self.is_kyc_verified.present?
    true
  end

end
```

As you can see the method initially used to return the `self.is_kyc_verified` which was false, which in turn resulted in "rollback of transaction" so I explicitly added a true at the end so it won't "rollback the transaction"

However I feel, that this is not the right way to implement this function.
Can you please review my code and suggest me the right way to do so?

Comment: What does "kyc status" mean, and when/why would you want to change it?

Comment: `is_kyc_verified` is flag which indicates that the customer has verified his know your customer details. but if he edits his personal information again i.e after he is being verified then he has to re-verify his details hence I need to set `is_kyc_verified` to false if he updates any info.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Maybe just change the `before_update` to execute when `#changed?` is true?</s>

<s>http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F</s>

EDIT: After looking at the question again, I'd change my answer. I think it's reasonable to return `true`. There's not really anyway around it, considering the way callbacks handle the return value. I suppose you could invert the values of the `is_kyc_verified` to be something like `is_kyc_unverified?`. But, that already seems confusing.

I do however think you should move the `unless: :is_kyc_verified_changed?` into the `change_kyc_status` method. I find the current flow a little hard to follow, as you must check in two places if `is_kyc_verified` will be set.

I might change it to something like:

```
before_update :confirm_is_kyc_verified
...
def confirm_is_kyc_verified
  if !is_kyc_verified.changed? && is_kyc_verified && valid?
    is_kyc_verified = false
  end

  true
end
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit? As it currently stands it's awfully minimal.

Comment: Good point @mast. After looking at the question again, I think it's incorrect anyway.